# Deja Vu? How do we keep the site alive?

Tags: discussion

First of all, I am happy to see this topic getting another go! I love the field, and wish to contribute as much as possible. So this was tried a while back, and sadly the site didn't survive. It ended up getting merged with Physics.  I am all open for ideas and suggestions to keep the site vibrant and going so that it can stay as its own site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, we have a vastly different set of users this time around - myself included. Thus, we have a *different* chance of making it to graduation. I don't know if our chances are better or worse.

Also, people simply need to ask and answer questions *and vote*! We can't moderate ourselves if people don't vote. One hump everyone needs to get over is people who are close to passing you in rep - vote for the content, not the user. Don't even look at the user before voting, actually. It's hard to get the hang of, but it feels liberating afterward, not being tied to only voting for people you think won't catch you.

Comment: Yeah, you've this nutter named UV-D, who loves this kind of science and loves to spend time researching the answers.